# How to diagnosis intermittent wireless network connectivity issue in linux when using netctl-auto?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-router

**Background**

archlinux latest version

I use netctl-auto and netctl to connect a wireless network.

The wireless network is from a television cable router.

The provider is Vodafone (Germany)

---

**Problem**

Sometimes when I boot the machine the wireless connection does not work.

e.g. ping does this

```
ping 8.8.8.8                                                                                                            
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

---

**What I have tried**

The only way to establish the connection is first stop the network and then start everything, i.e.

```
netctl stop wireless  
systemctl disable netctl-auto@wlp58s0.service
netctl-auto disable wireless 

systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlp58s0.service
netctl-auto enable wireless                                                                                      
netctl start wireless
```

Another solution is to switch off/on the cable router.

I have tried looking into the logs

```
sudo journalctl -u netctl.service
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-04-19 12:18:06 CEST, end at Sun 2020-02-09 11:54:12 CET. --
-- No entries --

sudo journalctl -u netctl-auto@.service
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-04-19 12:18:06 CEST, end at Sun 2020-02-09 11:54:27 CET. --
-- No entries --

sudo journalctl -u netctl@.service 
-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-04-19 12:18:06 CEST, end at Sun 2020-02-09 11:54:33 CET. --
-- No entries --
```

This is what systemctl says about those units

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files --all
netctl-auto@.service                                                      indirect       
netctl-ifplugd@.service                                                   disabled       
netctl-sleep.service                                                      disabled       
netctl-wait-online.service                                                disabled       
netctl.service                                                            disabled       
netctl@.service                                                           static         


systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled
autovt@.service                                                  enabled        
display-manager.service                                          enabled        
gdm.service                                                      enabled        
getty@.service                                                   enabled        
systemd-fsck-root.service                                        enabled-runtime
systemd-remount-fs.service                                       enabled-runtime
remote-fs.target                                                 enabled   

sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep disabled 
netctl-ifplugd@.service                                          disabled        
netctl-sleep.service                                             disabled                                                                         
netctl-wait-online.service                                       disabled                                                                        
netctl.service                                                   disabled
```

---

**Question**

1. How to diagnosis this problem?
2. When I switch the router off/on, linux (i.e. netctl-auto) seems to re-connect, I suspect this might not be  problem with my linux setup. Any ideas?

(This question was previously posted on Network Engineering)